# How to read a simple string from a POST request in AFNetworking (No JSON)

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking

I'm using `AFNetworking` to communicate with a server through POST that responds with a simple string containing the information I need.  I'm using the following code:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST: MY_URL
   parameters: MY_PARAMETERS
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //do something
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //etc.
      }];
```

However, it seems that `AFNetworking` expects every response to be in JSON format because I get this error when I execute my request:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x1566eb00
>   {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}

How can I tell `AFNetworking` that it's OK that the response is not a JSON object? I've seen something involving `AFHTTPClient`, but it doesn't seem to be part of `AFNetworking` anymore.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can tell the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` or `AFHTTPSessionManager` how to handle the response, e.g. before calling `POST`, you can do the following:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Then in your `success` block, you can convert the `NSData` to a string:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Having said that, you might want to contemplate converting your web service to return JSON response, as it's far easier to parse that way (and differentiate between a valid response and some server error).

Answer (score 2):

```
  NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

you can get response description details like below

```
 NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Much better way would be subclassing *AFHTTPResponseSerializer* and overriding there

> func responseObject(for response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error:
>   NSErrorPointer) -> Any?

There you can parse response, cast to type you need and return.