# AFNetworking handling response from php script

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am sending a post to a php script.

At the end the script echoes back a 'success' or 'fail' depending on what happens in the script.

At the moment I can't find a way to decode the response to check with the string is.

I set the responseSerializer to AFHTTPResponseSerializer.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"http://xyz.kphosting.com/IR/reg_user_name.php"
   parameters:parameters2
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
        {

          NSLog(@"Success Responce Object: %@", responseObject);
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

          NSLog(@"Fail Responce Object: %@", error.description);
      }];
```

The response I get back is:

> Success Responce Object: <4e6f7468 696e6720 746f2073 65652068 6572652e 2e2e>

How can I convert this to a string to check it is a success or fail?

PHP script does an echo as below

```
echo "Success";
```

Anybody able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: That response is the text `Nothing to see here...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `responseObject` is kind of `NSData`, so to get string value you must do the following:

```
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject 
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Success Response Message: %@", text);
```

Comment: This is correct; however, as noted in the answer to a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21024513/1671886), @Code, you should consider designing your php script to return JSON. You could achieve this by using `json_encode`. Then, I'd recommend subclassing `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, and overloading `validateResponse:data:error` to achieve the validation on your response.